# Probability with playing cards

Tags: probability, combinations

OK, so I am having a little problem with a question about probability, an area I am not good at. The problem goes like this:

You draw 5 cards separately without replacement from a standard deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that the colors alternate after each card? Ex. Black, Red, Black, Red, Black. I tried two methods, but they both give me different answers.

Method 1 (Multiplication):

$P=1\times \frac{26}{51}\times\frac{25}{50}\times\frac{25}{49}\times\frac{24}{48}=\frac{325}{4998}$

Method 2 (Combinations):

$\frac{{26\choose3} {26\choose2}}{{52}\choose{5}}=\frac{1625}{4998}$

I don't know which one is right, but I can guess it is the first one. Can you help me and tell me how I went wrong with either one of them, or both?

Comment: The second is the probability of drawing three blacks and two reds.

Comment: First method is correct. Doesn't matter what the first card is but the next card should be of opposite color than the previous card.

Comment: How would I fix method 2, or can I not use combinations in this way at all? (I get that the first way is easier, but I am bad at using combinations)